# OpenGL DrawElements using DYNAMIC_DRAW

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

Got the problem with dynamic draw and cant understand the reason of why it doesnt render. Heres the binding code

```
public void GenerateAttributesPolygonDynamic(ref int VBO, ref int VAO, ref int EBO, int ArrayLength, int IndiciesLength)
    {
        VBO = GL.GenBuffer();
        VAO = GL.GenVertexArray();
        EBO = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, sizeof(float) * ArrayLength, IntPtr.Zero, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, EBO);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, sizeof(uint) * IndiciesLength, IntPtr.Zero, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 2 * sizeof(float));
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    }
```

the VBO consists of 2 XY coordinates in float and 4 floats of RGBA. After this Binding I simple call draw function and doest see anything in canvas

```
public void Draw()
    {
        float[] Verticies = new float[]
        {
             -0.5f,  0.5f,   Color4.Red.R,Color4.Red.G,Color4.Red.B,Color4.Red.A,
              0.5f,  0.5f,   Color4.Red.R,Color4.Red.G,Color4.Red.B,Color4.Red.A,
              0.5f,  -0.5f,  Color4.Red.R,Color4.Red.G,Color4.Red.B,Color4.Red.A,
             -0.5f,  -0.5f,  Color4.Red.R,Color4.Red.G,Color4.Red.B,Color4.Red.A
        };
        uint[] Indicies = new uint[]
        {
            0, 1, 3,
            1, 2, 3
        };
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
        GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, sizeof(float) * Verticies.Length, Verticies);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, EBO);
        GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, sizeof(uint) * Indicies.Length, Indicies);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
        GL.UseProgram(ProgramID);
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, Indicies.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);

    }
```

Hope someone could help me. The shader is simple and correct and works fine on binding the STATIC_DRAW type. I need to use Dynamic_Draw method and BufferSubData for other problems while rendering objects dynamically, and this code is the sample where I stuck. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: The useage hint is only a _hint_, and the actual output should be exactly the same no matter which hint you specify (the performance may differ, though). So if your exact code works if you _only_ change that hint back to `STATIC_DRAW`, you either have some weird driver bug, or you may have some bug in your code, likely some undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I supposed that bugs could be, but this method runs only once (had written it before doing something serious) and once called for Render and without ElementsBuffer it could be rendered correctly (made a simple Lines around mouse cursor and it works fine). Really confused what is the problem.

Comment: There's no sign of any GL error checking code here. The runtime is probably telling you what the problem is, but you're not listening.

Comment: tried to put GL.GetError() in Draw method and got InvalidValue after VBO binding. Also checked after binding of EBO and got NoError. Confused how to solve problem :/

Answer (score 3):

The [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) is stored within the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). When you call `GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);` (and the VAO is bound), the binding is broken.

Remove

<s>`GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);`</s>

When a buffer is bound to the target `BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer`, then this buffer is associated to the vertex array object which is currently bound. This behaves different then the `BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer`.

When you initialize the indexes, it is sufficient to bind the VAO, as the index buffer was already assigned to the VAO before, in `GenerateAttributesPolygonDynamic`:

```cs
GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, IntPtr.Zero,
    sizeof(uint) * Indicies.Length, Indicies);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it doesnt help to render from GL.DrawElements still. But when I Remove ElementsBuffer totally, Dynamic Draw works fine, but it is not a solution to make much more Verticies and put the RGBA for each of them

Comment: @AlexanderMan I see. Anyway this is a bug in your application. Possibly there are some more.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. When method `GenerateAttributesPolygonDynamic` is called, I set incorrect ArrayLength parameter without bytes of Color. Thanks a lot for all of you. Topic needs to be closed.